# Conditional args in GraphQL mutations?

Tags: graphql, apollo

Let's say I have a `mutation` which has a `type` arg. Depending on the value of `type` I can either make a `mutation` accept another `arg` which is an input type or call `mutation` without it.

How to implement it in `graphql`? I know that for queries there're `@skip` and `@include` directives (for fields, not for args). Is there something similar for `mutations`? Or should I just specify the additional arg as optional and then do the validation on the server?

Answer (score 5):

There'll be a range of opinions on this. The main problem is that because you can't define unions for input types, you can't model inputs exhaustively at the schema level. By this I mean that if you need deeper validation than just required/not-required, GraphQL's type system won't help you.

At the moment I lean towards handling all complex validation in the mutation function itself. Essentially mark all input arguments as not required and let it fall through to a validation method of your choosing.

For simple mutations, like `do_foo_with_bar(bar_id: Int!)`, i'd still let the schema handle validation. But for more complex things (like an elaborate form), you're going to have an easier time if you do things in code.